# Does AWS EC2 have limits on concurrent connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ulimit

No matter what I do to my EC2 instance, any size and with apache/ubuntu.

I can't get it to go over 1400 concurrent connections.

Have set the prefork settings high, set ulimit to 1000000

Is this something to do with AWS?

Comment: Is it possible that the kernel is limiting the number of connections? What do you need more than 1400 connections for anyway?

Comment: What happens when you try to get more connections?

Comment: By default 1024 connection are aloowed in /etc/security/limits.conf , it can be increased upto 65535 connections max..

Comment: Check apache error log `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for specific error (ex: MaxClients maxed out)